# URL constructor doesn't work with some characters

Tags: swift, url, encoding

I'm trying to call a php-script from my app using URLRequest.
The Url path is generated in the String-Variable `query` and for the request I convert it like this

```
    guard let url = URL(string: query) else {
        print("error")
        return
    }
```

usually it works, but when the request contains characters like ä, ö, ü, ß the error is triggered. How can I make it work?

Comment: Did you try encoding decoding on String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `URL(string:)` initializer doesn't take care of encoding the `String` to be a valid URL `String`, it assumes that the `String` is already encoded to only contain characters that are valid in a `URL`. Hence, you have to do the encoding if your `String` contains non-valid URL characters. You can achieve this by calling `String.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)`.

```
let unencodedUrlString = "áűáeqw"
guard let encodedUrlString = unencodedUrlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed), let url = URL(string: encodedUrlString) else { return }
```

You can change the `CharacterSet` depending on what part of your URL contains the characters that need encoding, I just used `urlQueryAllowed` for presentation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Split your URL in two separate parts:

```
let baseURLString = "https://www.example.com"
let pathComponent = "áűáeqw"
let fullURL = URL(string: baseURLString)?.appendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
```